# git - how to replace Master?

Tags: git

I have a remote repo where my project is out of date.
I made new one local repo with new project, switched to new branch and made what I wanted. Now I want to push it (not changes - whole project) to that remote repo. How should I do that?

Comment: You want to push a branch that doesn't exist on the remote, is that it?

Comment: Yes. And no. I want to replace Master branch on Origin with non-master branch of local repo.

Comment: And you don't want to do the same to your local `master`?

Comment: Yes.. I was illogical, you are right. Well, now I merged Mater and that branch on local repo and in several seconds to try out "git push -f origin master". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just don't use the `-f` flag at the first try. `git push origin master` should work. `-f` could lose commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-f` argument to `git push` is probably what you want, it allows the receiving repo to be overwritten with unrelated changes. The older changes in the remote repo will still exist for a time but eventually be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

When using [`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) you can specify which branch to push from and which branch to push to:

```
git push origin localbranch:remotebranch
```

This could fail if the `remotebranch` is not an ancestor of the `localbranch`. If you use `-f` you can force an overwrite, but be careful, because this will lose commits.

But you probably want to just merge the two locally, and push this updated master.